# Using properties efficiently in inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I have a class called `Mailer` which has some properties like this

```
public static string Cname
{
   get
   {
      return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request["cname"]));
   }
   set
   {
      HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request["cname"]));
   }
}
```

I am inheriting this property from another class called `EventRegistrationReplyMail`
like this

```
public class EventRegistrationReplyMail :Mailer
```

and using `Cname` property inside this class. I doubt whether this is the correct way of doing things or not. I am just a beginner in OOP concepts, so please spare me if I am doing anything completely stupid.

Comment: Perhaps you could show more of the code like where you are using this and other surrounding code modules???

Comment: Don't use the word "[efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency)" to refer to things that have nothing to do with efficiency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Accessors in C#**
You should read on [accessors in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - your setter does not do what it should - it should *set* the value if `Cname`. If this has no meaning (you can't change the value of `Cname` - you should drop the `set` altogether.
Correct use of accessors:

```
public string Name 
{
   get 
   { 
      return name; 
   }
   set 
   {
      name = value; 
   }
}
```

For read only properties:

```
public static string Cname
{
   get
   {
      return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request["cname"]));
   }
}
```

**Inheritance and static members**
You are asking about efficiency in inheriting properties. I don't know what do you mean by "efficiently inheriting", but static members are not really [inherited](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/250972-Static-Inheritance/), you simply get some allowance from calling them in the inherited class...

> Inheritance in .NET works only on instance base. Static methods are
>   defined on the type level not on the instance level. That is why
>   overriding doesn't work with static methods/properties/events...

**Use of properties**
When using properties, you imply *state* of the object you are writing the property on (in this case - `Mailer` class). From looking at your code, it does not look like its the class's *state*, but rather a calculation made.
A better choice would be to write it as a utility method, which makes it clear that you are calculating something in it:

```
public static string ExtractCNameFromCurrentRequest() {
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
       HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request["cname"]));
}
```

Or you could use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx), which will result in a cool usage syntax, and make clear from where you are extracting the `CName`:

```
public static class HttpContextExtension {
    public static string GetCName(this HttpContext context) {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(context.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request["cname"]));
    }
}
```

And its usage will be:

```
string cname = HttpContext.Current.GetCName();
```

Answer (score 3):

@UriAgassi made very good points, I'm just going to add a few thoughts:

- In the context of a `Mailer` class, the name `Cname` isn't absolutely clear. One of the benefits of *encapsulation*, is the possibility for *abstraction* - the code that uses a `Mailer` object doesn't need to know/care that the HTTP context has a value called "cname". `ContactName` is probably a much more meaningful name.

> *I am inheriting this property from another class called `EventRegistrationReplyMail`*

You're not, it's the other way around: the `EventRegistrationReplyMail` class is inheriting this property from its base class `Mailer`.

---

What you have here isn't a property, it's a *method in disguise* (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601648/1188513) for more info); properties should be simple and straightforward, and shouldn't throw exceptions - methods are *actions*, properties are *data*.

Like Uri Agassi, what I'd recomment you have here instead, is a method - this way if any exception is thrown, it will be less surprising ([POLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)) than if it were a property.

Lastly, I'd also recommend separating what's going on in that one-liner, so as to reduce the number of method calls in a single instruction, which increases readability and can make the code self-explanatory with good variable naming:

```
public string DecodeCNameFromQueryString()
{
    var encodedName = HttpContext.Current.Request["cname"];
    var decodedName = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(encodedName);
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(decodedName);
}
```

Per [Difference between UrlEncode and HtmlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812486/1188513), I don't think you actually need to make both calls - perhaps you could test whether this returns the same value:

```
public string DecodeCNameFromQueryString()
{
    var encodedName = HttpContext.Current.Request["cname"];
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(encodedName);
}
```

And then I'm guessing your `HttpContext.Current.Request` would have other query string parameters, so you'd probably be better off with a more generic method that takes a `string` parameter representing the query string parameter:

```
public string DecodeQueryStringParameterValue(string parameterName)
{
    var encodedName = HttpContext.Current.Request[parameterName];
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(encodedName);
}
```